# Tinymce 4.0.28 security vulnerabilities

Tags: security, tinymce

Please can any one list out the Tinymce 4.0.28 version security vulnerabilities and solution for the vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two places to look:

- [Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures (CVE)](https://cve.mitre.org/cve/) database
- NIST's [National Vulnerability Database (NVD)](https://nvd.nist.gov)

Here are links for 'Tinymce' searches:

- [NVD](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=Tinymce&search_type=all&cves=on)
- [CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=tinymce)

You would need to look through those and see if they were patched and if they are relevant to your specific situation.

**CVE and NVD Relationship**

From [About CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/about/cve_and_nvd_relationship.html)

The CVE List feeds NVD, which then builds upon the information included in CVE Entries to provide enhanced information for each entry such as fix information, severity scores, and impact ratings. As part of its enhanced information, NVD also provides advanced searching features such as by OS; by vendor name, product name, and/or version number; and by vulnerability type, severity, related exploit range, and impact.